# How to get sizeof not yet defined struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

```
struct S1
{
    size_t v = sizeof(S2); //compiler error here
};

struct S2
{
    S1 s1;
};
```

the struct S2 needs to be below S1 so it can have it as a member, but I also want the sizeof(S2) to be stored in S1.

I made a workaround where I put a function prototype that returns the sizeof(S2) but is defined after S2 is defined, like so:

```
size_t func();

struct S1
{
    size_t v = func();
};

struct S2
{
    S1 s1;
};

size_t func()
{
    return sizeof(S2);
}
```

But I feel like this is a really ugly and bad solution, is there a better way?

Comment: You can't get the size of something that hasn't been fully defined yet.  Your workaround looks reasonable to me. Why does S1 need to store the size of S2 in the first place? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: the better solution is to get rid of the cyclic dependency so that you can have one struct fully defined before the other

Comment: Why not `S1::S1() : v{sizeof(S2)} {}` instead of `func()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a constructor rather than the in class initializer the issue is gone:

```
struct S1
{
    size_t v;
    S1();
};

struct S2
{
    S1 s1;
};

S1::S1() : v(sizeof(S2)) {}
```

Answer (score 10):

Since `sizeof` is an compile time operator, it makes sense to declare `v` as a (constant) static data member (not bound to class instance), e.g.

```
struct S1
{
    static const size_t v; //declare as static
};

struct S2
{
    S1 s1;
};

//then

const size_t S1::v = sizeof(S2); //define it after S2 is defined
```

or as global variable

```
inline constexpr size_t S2_size = sizeof(S2); //often used as shortcut/alias
                                              //does not do much here
```

---

Based on the comments below:

```
struct S1
{
    size_t v;
    S1(size_t s) : v{s} {}
};

struct S2
{
    S1 s1;
    S2() : s1{sizeof(S2)} {}
};

struct S3
{
    S1 s1;
    S3() : s1{sizeof(S3)} {}
};

//...
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make it a global constant? For my case I want S1.v to change depending on the instance.

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi On which instance?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük What I meant is, I want to be able to do this:
```
S1 s;
S1 ss;
s.v += 10;
ss.v += 20;
```

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi If you want to aggregate `S1` in multiple classes (and therefore store the size of that particular class), then introduce a constructor `S1(size_t size)` and initialize `s1` within the constructor of that class, e.g. `SN::SN() : s1{sizeof(SN)} {}`.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük yeah that makes more sense. I'll do that.

Comment: `sizeof(S2)` is a compile time constant but that does not imply that `v` is static

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I'm not 100% sure of what you mean, Don't get me wrong, my intention is not to contradict you but in which sense does that matter? The main focus was on, that a compile time constant doesn't need to be bound to a object instance (hence static data member).

Comment: in OPs code you can do `S1 a,b;   a.v = 42; b.v = 24;`. Just because the initializer is a compile time constant does not imply that the member is too. However, seems like thats what op wants. In the question they also write "I also want the sizeof(S2) to be stored in S1" so it seems like their initial `size_t v` (no `const`, no `static`) was just off

Comment: well actually no. They write in their comment "For my case I want S1.v to change depending on the instance." Thats what I meant

Answer (score 3):

You could use a template.

```
template<class T>
struct S1
{
    size_t v = sizeof(T);
};

struct S2
{
    S1<S2> s1;

    void get()
    {
        std::cout << s1.v;
    }

};


int main()
{
    S2 s2;
    s2.get();
}
```